# Invoke-Command Powershell parameter issue

Tags: powershell

I need to pass a comma delimited parameter to a batch file via powershell and can't seem to get it to work.  Here's how I call the batch file if I call it directly in powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Mike> type zz.cmd
@echo off
echo/* = [%*}
echo/1 = [%1]
echo/2 = [%2]
echo/3 = [%3]
pause
PS C:\Users\Mike> cmd /c zz "q,w,e"
* = [q,w,e}
1 = [q]
2 = [w]
3 = [e]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If I use cmd /c zz """q,w,e""" or cmd /c zz '"q,w,e"' I will get "q,w,e" for arg 1.  This is good.  However, I must call powershell using Invoke-Command.  When doing this, the script doesn't work:

```
powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { "cmd /c E:\\npoess\\oo\\WoD\\zzz" '"q,w,e"'}
```

Any idea how to get the powershell call from the command prompt to get "q,w,e" as one parameter to the batch file?

Thanks,

-Mike

Comment: Why are you invoking `powershell.exe` for the sole purpose of running `cmd.exe`? What prevents you from running `cmd.exe` directly? Adding layers of indirection isn't going to help get things done.

Comment: "However, I must call powershell using Invoke-Command." Why?

Comment: I need to use powershell to pass along user credentials

Comment: I also have the same question as alroc. I think you need to explain more of your goal rather than your attempted solution.

Comment: I'm trying to call a batch file that requires elevated permissions to run it.  The user will hit a button and the batch script will be called in the background but the user does not have the permissions to launch the script.  Instead, when the software is installed we will save the user credentials required via powershell.  I want to use those credentials to launch the batch script.  So, I can't call the batch script directly.

Comment: Are you asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt?

Comment: Yes, I need to bypass that and execute the script even if the user running the script (or app) isn't launched with the proper privledges.

Comment: You can't bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design. See [FAQ: Why can't I bypass the UAC prompt?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/06/29/faq-why-can-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt.aspx) for a good explanation.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing that then.  Our users don't have permission to execute scripts.  With a different account, the script can be executed.  We already do this with different scripts.  This particular script needs a single param with multiple values passes as a comma delimited string.

Comment: "Our users don't have permission to execute scripts" - Do you mean that PowerShell execution policy prevents you from running scripts in PowerShell, or something else? I think you need to clarify what you want to do, not how you think it needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

this invoke-command without all the quotes works for passing a for me :
I *think* that the quotes around the variables passes the set as a string instead of separate values.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
     cmd /c C:\scripts\zz.cmd q,w,e
     }
```

Comment: I tried powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { cmd /c C:\scripts\zz.cmd q,w,e } and it failed to pass the set together.